# .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava

Tags: r, rjava

I am running Win 10 64-bi with Java version 1.8.0.221. when loading xlsx package I am getting an error in R Studio with version 3.5.2 - also 64-bit.
The error is in loading rJava.
any thoughts on how can I fix this? I am stuck and can't move forward. Thanks.

```
trying URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2019-02-01/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/xlsx_0.6.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 458979 bytes (448 KB)
downloaded 448 KB

package ‘xlsxjars’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘xlsx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIZaYPe\downloaded_packages
> library(xlsx)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/<user>/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Most questions are older and hence may not be relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following and then rJava loaded without error.

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_221')
```

Comment: Perhaps you should revise or delete [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347446/onload-failed-in-loadnamespace-for-rjava?noredirect=1#comment103050555_58347446) where you said *"Most questions are older and hence may not be relevant"*, since your answer here is **exactly** (version/release number notwithstanding) what is in the other question.

Comment: This will only work for the current session. Maybe edit Rprofile?!

Comment: Yes, I added this to .RProfile.

As for older versions, I was not sure if there was a change due to package and R version changes and wanted to make sure to find the latest info.